# Difference between Xdebug-profiler and Xdebug-tracer

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

What is the difference between Xdebug profiler and tracer? Is there one?

I know that they have different settings but I would like to know what their difference is in terms of functionality.

Comment: One traces execution - everything a program does. The other collects profiling/timing information, typically at the function call level.